# Register a taxonomy that is related to a post

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

Basically, I'm trying to code a rating system.

I have `Rating` and `Listing` custom post type. What I want to do is register a taxonomy on `Rating` that will show which post is rated from `Listing` custom post type. Furthermore, I want on `Listing` to be able to register a taxonomy that shows the average of all ratings on that post.
I have searched for similar question so far and I found only taxonomies related to a meta-box which I'm not interested since I want the custom post types to be added from front-end.

```
function create_post_type_listing()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'makedir-listing'); // Register Taxonomies for Category
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'makedir-listing');
    register_post_type('makedir-listing', // Register Custom Post Type
        array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Listing Post', 'makedirlisting'),
            'singular_name' => __('Listing Post', 'makedirlisting'),
            'add_new' => __('Add New', 'makedirlisting'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Listing Post', 'makedirlisting'),
            'edit' => __('Edit', 'makedirlisting'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Listing Post', 'makedirlisting'),
            'new_item' => __('New Listing Post', 'makedirlisting'),
            'view' => __('View Listing Post', 'makedirlisting'),
            'view_item' => __('View Listing Post', 'makedirlisting'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Listing Post', 'makedirlisting'),
            'not_found' => __('No Listing Posts found', 'makedirlisting'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Listing Posts found in Trash', 'makedirlisting')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'thumbnail'
        ),
        'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
        'taxonomies' => array(
            'post_tag',
            'category'
        ) // Add Category and Post Tags support
    ));
    register_taxonomy(
        'rating',
        'makedir-listing',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Rating' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'rating' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'show_ui'           => false,
            'show_admin_column' => true
        )
    );
}

function create_post_type_rating()
{
    register_post_type('makedir-rating', // Register Custom Post Type
        array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Rating', 'makedirrating'),
            'singular_name' => __('Rating', 'makedirrating'),
            'add_new' => __('Add New', 'makedirrating'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Rating', 'makedirrating'),
            'edit' => __('Edit', 'makedirrating'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Rating', 'makedirrating'),
            'new_item' => __('New Rating', 'makedirrating'),
            'view' => __('View Ratings', 'makedirrating'),
            'view_item' => __('View Rating', 'makedirrating'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Rating', 'makedirrating'),
            'not_found' => __('No Ratings found', 'makedirrating'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Ratings found in Trash', 'makedirlisting')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
        'has_archive' => false,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
        ),
        'can_export' => true // Allows export in Tools > Export
    ));
    register_taxonomy(
        'post',
        'makedir-rating',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Post' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'post' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'show_ui'           => false,
            'show_admin_column' => true
        )
    );
}
```

You can see where I struggle to implements the mentioned functions, at the bottom of each function. Hope I made it clear enough.

Comment: Have you tried to create anything? Please share some concrete code. Without code we will not be able to help you.

Comment: @jrswgtr Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think taxonomies are the right way to go here.

You are better off adding a custom field (try advanced custom fields/acf to make this easy https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)  I think. Add a post relationship or post object field to your rating post type, which can then link to the listing.

You can then write code to look up/calculate any aggregate data - like averages, number of ratings etc. And potentially save/cache these to custom fields / meta on the listing object if performance there is a concern.

Comment: Completely agree that ACF custom field would be the way to go, using a relationship field type which will already pull through the `Listing` post_type posts